# Link to ivars or methods with Doxygen

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I tried following the Doxygen documentation to add links to ivars and methods but none of them are interpreted by Doxygen.

This is what I'm doing.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
  int x;
}
@end

Somewhere else:
/**
Trying to link to x.
MyClass::x
*/
```

SOLUTION: No link is created to something that is not documented. Just added documentation to my ivar and the link was created.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using @interface instead of @class?

Comment: Sorry, the post has been corrected. It was a mistake writing the code. I cannot live without autocorrection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/** Class documentation. */
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
    /** This documentation is for x. */
    int x;
}
@end


/** @page mypage A page
    This is a \ref MyClass::x "link" to x.
    This also links to x: MyClass::x.
 */
```

Comment: There was no need to add the `\ref`. I was pointing to an ivar that was not documented so no link were created.